# Windows 10 IoT Core, Sharing SPI data

Tags: multithreading, win-universal-app, spi, windows-10-iot-core

My windows 10 IOT core application uses SPI to collect change notifications of 
many entities.  There are excellent examples for launching a timer to get SPI data, update data and binding UI elements to this data. The result is anytime SPI gets some data about a changed entity, the data that drives the UI is updated and any UI element bound to this data is updated. I can even change what subset of data is displayed on this page by using two way bindings to track the selected items on a list.

Just like the many examples, my code is structured as follows:

```
public async void Init_SPI()
        {
           ....
            periodicTimer = new Timer(this.TimerCallback, null, 0, 10);
        } // public async void Init_SPI()

 private void TimerCallback(object state)
        {
            /* UI updates must be invoked on the UI thread */
            var task =
             this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            { ... update states of data that many be bound to UI element
```

My issue / question:

I don't see how to update data for multiple pages based on the above, since  this.variable refers to the UI thread of the page that launched the timer.

It would be too inefficient to update a static class and have the multiple pages continuously poll this static data to make the UI track these large number of element.

My only thought at present is to code all the XAML pages in one page and tab between these "virtual" pages.  I would rather have multiple pages to keep the functionality of these pages separated.

Any suggestions for how I could update multiple pages from data read on a SPI port would be appreciated.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for a very late answer, but my solution would be to still create "real" pages -- but "relayed" the data only to the currently visible page. So whenever a page becomes visible I would have made the internals of the code piece above `{ ... update states of data [...]` to point out *that* page.
This could be achieved with a simple `switch` statement, or by a simple interface with a `HandleSpiData(TheSpiData)` method -- or even a simple `Action<YourSpiData>`.